# Message: Trying to get property 'total_precio' of non-object

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, php7, codeigniter-3

Estoy tratando de mostrar un reporte al momento de filtrar desde botón de mi vista  me arroja el siguiente mensaje

```
A PHP Error was encountered
```

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'total_precio' of non-object

Filename: reportes/Report.php

Line Number: 86

La linea 86 en el controlador tengo de la siguiente manera.

```
        foreach ($query as $q) {
        $compra = $this->compraT($q->cod_producto, $almacen, $anio, $mes);
        $q->compra_precio = (float)$compra->total_precio;
        $q->compra_cantidad = (int)$compra->total_numero;
```

Codigo de funcion compraT

```
    private function compraT($producto, $almacen, $anio, $mes)
{
    return $this->db->from('tb_compra_d')
        ->select("SUM(cant_compdet) as total_numero, SUM(precventa_compdet) as total_precio, AVG(precunit_compdet) - AVG(precunit_compdet * ($this->igv / 100)) as promedio_precio")
        ->join('tb_compra', 'tb_compra_d.cod_comp = tb_compra.cod_comp')
        ->where('cod_producto', $producto)
        ->where('cod_almacen', $almacen)
        ->where('YEAR(fecha_comp)', $anio)
        ->where('MONTH(fecha_comp)', $mes)
        ->group_by('cod_producto')
        ->get()->row();
```

Desde ya agradezco su respuesta.

Comment: La variable `$compra` no fue completada con un objeto, o al menos, no con un objeto con la propiedad `price`. Sin saber cómo está escrito `compraT` o que te llega en `$query`, es casi imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya edite mi pregunta ahí adjunte el código de la función compraT